# Antd getFieldDecorator()'s options trigger not working

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have the following code:

```
<FormItem {...formItemLayout} label="Name">
  {getFieldDecorator(
    `category[categories_langs][${index}][name]`,
    {
      rules: [
        {
          required: required,
          message: "Please input category name!"
        }
      ],
      validateTrigger: "onBlur",
      trigger: 'onBlur'
    }
  )(
      <Input
        name={`category[categories_langs][${index}][name]`}
        key={index}
      />
  )}
</FormItem>
```

When I add the `trigger: 'onBlur'` the Input component doesn't show the text that i enter. The idea is for Antd to collect the text I type on blur, because on onChange it's very slow. Also, this example works if I wrap the Input in a `<div>` which is strange. What am I doing wrong, and how do I make antd to collect the typed text onBlur, not on change? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There may be other issues with your code, but `required` in the validation rule should be `true`.

https://github.com/react-component/form#option-object